# Prove: If $\phi:R\rightarrow R'$ is a ring homomorphism, then $image(\phi)$ is a subring of $R'$

Tags: ring-theory

Do I have to use the regular axioms for proving something is a subring? i.e. closed under subtraction and multiplication.
If so, can I say $$im(r-s)=r-s\in R$$ $$im(rs)=rs\in R$$ Therefore $im(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $R'$? Do I have some notation mixed up? Or am I just thinking about it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your notation a little mixed up.  I'll get you started by showing that $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is closed under addition.

Assume $x, y \in \operatorname{im}(\phi) \subseteq R'$.  Then $\exists r, s \in R \text{ such that } \phi(r)=x, \phi (s)=y$.  Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $\phi(r+s)=\phi(r)+\phi(s)=x+y$, so $x+y \in \operatorname{im}(\phi)$.  Thus, $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is closed under addition.

Can you finish off the proof from there?

Comment: I think so, multiplication and subtraction follow similarly, right?

$\phi(rs)=\phi(r)\phi(s)=xy$, so $xy\in\operatorname{im}(\phi)$

$\phi(r-s)=\phi(r+(-s))=\phi(r)+\phi(-s)=x+(-y)=x-y$, so $x-y\in\operatorname{im}(\phi)$?

Comment: All correct.  You've got it.

Answer (score 0):

So, in other words this image is not necessarly a subring, but, instead, is an ideal of $\mathit{R'}$.

Comment: I don't think so because I'm not necessarily saying that it will absorb product from $R'$, just that subtraction holds.